# datetime data type in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I had a field in my mysql table and its datatype was `datetime`  and default value was `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. I thought it will put this value only on insert. This was getting changed both on Insert and update. Is it proper ?

I don't have `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` , then also its updating that column.

My question is like if i just have a column with datatype `datetime` and default as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` will it change the column when update on record happens even if `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is not there?

Comment: `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` ???

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you have:

```sql
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

However, it appears you're wanting:

```
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

The difference between these two, is that the first will update the timestamp column on both inserts and updates, and the second will only supply a TIMESTAMP during insert and will *NOT* update upon update of the row.

You can check what your table is using by using the `DESCRIBE` function within MySQL to describe a specific table's schema.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score 0):

From [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

With both `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, the column has the current timestamp for its default value and is automatically updated to the current timestamp.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

With neither `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` nor `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, it is the same as specifying both `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP
);
```

With a `DEFAULT` clause but no `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` clause, the column has the given default value and is not automatically updated to the current timestamp.

The default depends on whether the `DEFAULT` clause specifies `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or a constant value. With `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, the default is the current timestamp.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```